How to grant android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" permission to device owner app in android
I have tried below code.
val dpm = context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
val componentName = ComponentName(context, SampleReceiver::class.java)
dpm.setPermissionGrantState(componentName, context.packageName, "android.permission.DUMP", DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED)

It didn't work.
